# Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance setting up domain name

Tags: domains, dns, apache2, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I had a domain transferred to amazon using their Rout 53.  at the begining when i went to the IP address 54.69.253.182, or ec2-54-69-253-182.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com  my site would show up.  Currently I have set up some Record Sets in the hosted zones that direct the url(not sure if this is correct or not).  Now if you go to either the IP address or the ec2 address it redirects to www.bracketfanatic.com and shows "Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.bracketfanatic.com Did you mean: www.­bracketfanatics.­com".

/etc/hostname : bracketfanatic.com
apache2ctl configtest returns :

```
"sudo: unable to resolve host bracketfanatic.com 
AH00557: apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for bracketfanatic.com
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domainname, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
```

sudo hostname ruturns:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host bracketfanatic.com
bracketfanatic.com
```

What I need:  go to the url www.bracketfanatic.com or bracketfanatic.com it shows my site.
I am brand new to amazon ec2, so please be specific.  Any help or point in the right direction would be nice.  If more information is needed, please just ask. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your host name also needs to be added to */etc/hosts* in 127.0.0.1 section.  If you haven't rebooted since editing */etc/hostname* you also need to set the hostname using the `hostname` command.  This normally happens at bootup from */etc/hostname*.

Here is a script that I use to make sure the host name is set correctly on my Ubuntu ec2 instance:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

etchostname=`cat /etc/hostname`
if [ `echo "$etchostname" | grep -c '\.'` -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "ERROR: /etc/hostname does not contain a fully qualified domain name."
    echo "edit /etc/hostname and try again"
    exit 1
fi

if [ `grep 127.0.0.1 /etc/hosts | grep -c "$etchostname"` -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Adding hostname to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts"
    sudo sed -i -r "s/^127.0.0.1([ \t].*)/127.0.0.1 $etchostname \\1/g" /etc/hosts
fi

hostname=`hostname -f` || true
if [ "$hostname" != "$etchostname" ]
then
    echo "Setting hostname to $etchostname"
    sudo hostname "$etchostname"
fi
```

---

To solve the Apache message you will also have to create a configuration file for Apache using these commands [source](https://askubuntu.com/a/396048/53750):

```
echo "ServerName localhost" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf-available/servername.conf
sudo a2enconf servername
sudo service apache2 reload
```

---

You also need to set up DNS hosting for your website.    To do so using route 53 you would log into the AWS admin console and navigate to route 53.   You would then "Create hosted zone".   In that hosted zone create records for the base domain (bracketfanatic.com.) and www.bracketfanatic.com.   They could either be A records that point to your elastic IP address (54.69.253.182), or CNAME records that point to ec2-54-69-253-182.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.

You will then need to copy the NS records from that hosted zone into your domain name registrar.  If you are using GoDaddy, you would first "launch" your domain.  Then you would choose "manage nameservers" and paste in the four values that Route 53 supplied for you.

Comment: thank you for the post.  How do I run that script?

Comment: You need to paste it into a file, make it runnable, and execute it.   Try this: `nano /tmp/hostname.sh && chmod +x /tmp/hostname.sh && /tmp/hostname.sh`

Comment: This script returns:
   
    ERROR: /etc/hostname does not contain a fully qualified   domain name.
edit /etc/hostname and try again

I then changed /etc/hostname : bracketfanatic (removing the .com), and i get the same error.

Comment: It should have the `.com`.  The script is making sure that it does.  `echo bracketfanatic.com | grep -c '\.'` gives me "1" (which shouldn't equal zero) so I'm not sure why the script is failing for you if "bracketfanatic.com" is what you have in */etc/hostname*  You can run `cat /etc/hostname` to check that it is set the way that you expect (with the .com)

Comment: when i run "echo bracketfanatic.com | grep -c '\.'" gives me "1", and when i run "cat /etc/hostname" it returns bracketfanatic.com.
Do i maybe need to restart apache2 or the instance for this to work?

Comment: Since the script isn't working for you, you can just edit */etc/hosts* manually with `sudo nano /etc/hosts` and insert  bracketfanatic.com after "127.0.0.1" and a space.

Comment: This is what is already in my /etc/hosts file:

127.0.0.1 bracketfanatic.com  localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

After rebooting, and running apache2ctl configtest i get Syntax OK

Comment: Sounds good.  The warnings that you are getting aren't really the problem.  While it would be nice to make them go away, you need to move on to the DNS hosting setup that I have in the last two paragraphs.

Comment: So i added a picture of my record sets and i think they are correct.  As for as the domain name registrar, the domain was transferred to amazon and I am not sure what to do from there. I believe it started at godaddy.

Comment: If your domain registrar is Amazon, you can edit the nameservers under the domain settings.   Instructions are here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/registrar.html#domain-edit-settings

Comment: I add/edit name servers and it notified me that i would receive an email when it is done.  Hopefully that worked.  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: So I received an email from amazon saying that the name servers were changed.  Now when i go to the site i get "This webpage has a redirect loop".  I think it's because of my hosted record sets, but i am not sure.